# How can you receive ISS broadcast using a Baofeng?

Tags: baofeng

I have a Baofeng UV-5R with stock and a Nagoya 701 (maybe fake?) antennas and wonder how I can receive voice from ISS astronauts? Do they have a schedule for going on air?

I live in Romania so probably I have more chance receiving signals for Russian headquarters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frequency 145825 kHz FM when ISS is within 800 km from your geographical position. That corresponds with visual line between ISS and your location.

Normal transmission is digital (FSK) and very sporadic you can hear voice. Doppler effect on frequency requires tuning of plus and minus 3.5 kHz (2.5 or 5 kHz) higher and/or lower frequency.

Position of the ISS can be found here: https://www.astroviewer.net/iss/en/

Forecast for ISS pass-over for your location can be found on [www.heavens-above.com](http://www.heavens-above.com) (do not forget to set your location!).

Communication with ISS requires minus 600 kHz TX offset: TX on 145.225 Mhz.

Fake antenna Nagoya 701 analysis: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrcY7adFBbw

Succes,

PA0FSB

Comment: Adding to that, I've received signals with a magnet mount in my car.  Unless they've changed it with the new equipment just installed, voice downlink is usually on 145.800.  There's a a packet digipeater on 145.825.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that the ISS broadcasts two things: SSTV (image broadcast), which is done once in a while for a week or two at a time, and repeater mode, which was added recently and is always functional. On a side note, the last time they broadcasted, a friend and I noticed that they don't seem to broadcast SSTV when the area they're over is dark. Not sure though.

Answer (score 2):

I have a UV-5R with the stock antenna. I've been able to successfully listen to astronaut contacts with schools on 144.825 MHz and to the new cross-band voice repeater downlink on 437.800 MHz. You need to find out when the various modes are active. (The voice repeater worked for a couple of weeks then went off-air.)

I use the Android app version of the [heavens-above](https://www.heavens-above.com/) website to tell me when the ISS is within range and the ISS Now app by VKL Apps for an easier display of where the ISS is when out of range as well as various space and launch videos. (Other apps exist but I haven't tried them.)